# Understanding django.shortcuts.redirect

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I have a couple problems understanding how `redirect` or rather `reverse` really work.

In the main urls.py I have:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/monitor/'}),
        url(r'^monitor/', include('monitor.urls')),
)
```

and in `monitors.urls` I have:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 

urlpatterns = patterns('monitor.views',
        (r'^$', 'index'),
        (r'^abc/(?P<id>.*$)', 'abc'),
)
```

When you call `/monitor` I want to redirect it to `/monitor/abc` so I did:

```
def index(request):
    return redirect("abc")

def abc(render, id=None):
    return render_to_response("monitor/list.htmld", {})
```

But I got an `NoReverseMatch` exception. But when I do:

```
def index(request):
    return redirect("abc/")
```

then it suddenly works.

I cannot fully understand why. Why did `reverse` fail with `abc` but not with `abc/`? And how does `reverse` know that the redirect should include `monitor/` as well? What if I had in the main urls.py another app called `xyz` which also has a `abc` view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did reverse fail with 'abc' but not with 'abc/'?

Because it interpreted it as a view name (and you indeed have a view named `'abc'`, see your `monitor.urls` file). This means Django will call `reverse` to compute the URL. The value `abc/` is interpreted as an actual URL which means Django won't call `reverse` to determine the URL.

This also explains why `reverse` failed: the view with name `abc` also requires an argument called `id`. Otherwise Django won't be able to lookup the URL as there is no view called `abc` without parameters.

Based on [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) you should be able to reverse the URL using:

```
redirect("abc", id=...)
```

where `...` is the value of the `id` parameter.

> And how does reverse know that the redirect should include monitor/ as well?

That is because it knows what URLs are available and 1) it knows where the view called `abc` is defined and 2) it knows that `monitors.urls` is included with `monitor/` in front.

> What if I had in the main urls.py another app called "xyz" which also has a "abc" view?

In that case you have to use [namespaces](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#defining-url-namespaces).

Comment: Thanks for the replay.

But when I do `return redirect('abc', id=8)` I still get a NoReverseMatch. The error message is "Reverse for 'abc' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id': 8}' not found." Should I include the request element somewhere?

Comment: when I do `return redirect(abc, id = 8)` then it worked, too. I still have some confusion :(