# understading django.shortcuts.reverse, part 2

Tags: django

In [Understanding django.shortcuts.redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938458/understading-django-shortcuts-redirect) I started a thread about `reverse` and `redirect_to`.

I still have some problems understanding how `reverse` works when the first parameter is a string. I read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.redirect many times and the corresponding part with `reverse`. But I am still getting a `NoReverseMatch` exception.

In my `ROOT_URLCONF` I have

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/monitor/'}),
    url(r'^monitor/', include('monitor.urls')),
)
```

In `monitor.urls` I have

```
urlpatterns = patterns('monitor.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^list', 'listall'),
)
```

and in `monitor.urls` I've defined code for both functions, `index` and `listall`. In `listall` I added the following lines:

```
def listall(request):
    <more code goes here>
    print "reversing 1 index: %s " % reverse(index)
    print "reversing 2 index: %s " % reverse('index')
    render_to_response("monitor/list.htmld", params)
```

If I visit localhost:3000/monitor/list then I can see

```
reversing 1 index: /monitor/
```

and nothing else, the second `reverse` raises an exception. Why? What am I missing?

I tracked it down to djangos code `django.core.urlresolvers.callable` and `django.core.urlresolvers.get_mod_func`. `get_mod_func` seems to expect something like "a.b", thats why in `callable` the very first line returned "index" for `func_name` but an empty string for `mod_name`. I changed my second line to

```
    print "reversing 2 index: %s " % reverse('monitor.views.index')
```

and it worked as intended. So, why do I need to call `reverse` with the full module and function name (when I use strings) and the documentation doesn't? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, reverse expects to be able to find a URL pattern by it's `name` parameter, or the fully qualified path to the function being called.

Comment: use `url()` as an items of urlpatterns in `monitor.urls` (same as in `ROOT_URLCONF`) - `url()` has optional `name` attribute, which is string that can be used as a string parameter for 'reverse'

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko: I cannot fully understand what you mean :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what part of the documentation you're hung up on, but `reverse`'s first parameter is some identifying method of getting to a view: it can be either a urlpattern name, a full dotted path to the view, or the view itself

So, based on your example, the first method is out because you didn't define a name for your urlpattern. Your first try, `reverse(index)` worked because you literally passed it the view. Your second try, `reverse('index')`, doesn't work because it need the full import context, i.e. `'monitor.views.index'`. The difference between the two is that when it's a string, Django must interpret that string to create an import for the view -- and 'index' is not enough information to determine the import path.

However, it's far, far better to just name your views if you intend on reversing them, and you should also namespace your included urlpatterns so two different apps don't end up conflicting. So in the project-level urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/monitor/'}),
    url(r'^monitor/', include('monitor.urls', namespace='monitor', app_name='monitor')),
)
```

Then, in monitor/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('monitor.views',
    (r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
    (r'^list', 'listall', name='listall'),
)
```

Then, reversing is as simple as `reverse('monitor:index')`.

Answer (score 2):

you should be doing something like

```
reverse('monitor:index')
```

In `ROOT_URLCONF` I have

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^$', redirect_to, {'url': '/monitor/'}),
   (r'^monitor/', include('monitor.urls'),namespace='monitor'),
)
```

and in `monitor.url.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('monitor.views',
   url(r'^$', 'index',name='index'),
)
```

for more details look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse

Comment: `(r'^$', 'index',name='index'),` generates and syntax error :(